# How to pass a context through django's rest_framework

Tags: python, django, response, httpresponse, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a view that returns a regular html-response if not otherwise specified. I'm using django's rest_framework to return a JSON if requested.

All works just fine except the part where I want to access my context inside the template.

Here's little code example, based on pictures:

```
@api_view(('GET', ))
@renderer_classes((TemplateHTMLRenderer, UnicodeJSONRenderer, JSONRenderer, BrowsableAPIRenderer))
def index(request):
    queryset = Picture.objects.all()

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    paginator = Paginator(queryset, 25)
    try:
        pictures = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        pictures = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        pictures = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    serializer_context = {'request': request, 'pictures': pictures, 'filter': FilterForm()}
    serializer = PaginatedPictureSerializer(pictures, context=serializer_context)
    return Response(serializer.data, template_name='index.html')
```

New when I want to access my context inside the template:

```
{% if pictures %}
      {% for picture in pictures %}
          ...
      {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No pictures are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

The result is always: No pictures are available (and debuging says the same).

**EDIT:**
as requested

```
class PictureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Picture


class PaginatedPictureSerializer(pagination.PaginationSerializer):

    class Meta:
        object_serializer_class = PictureSerializer
```

Comment: Please show us the `PaginatedPictureSerializer` definition.

Comment: @mariodev here you go, regular of the shelf (or rather doc) class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with rendering multiple context items is that you don't have access to their keys inside of a template. You need to hack on it a lil' bit.

There's a [relevant SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925358/how-do-you-access-data-in-the-template-when-using-drf-modelviewset-and-templateh) I have answered, which solves this issue. So basicaly you do:

```
serializer_context = {'request': request, 'pictures': pictures, 'filter': FilterForm()}

if request.accepted_renderer.format == 'html':
    return Response(serializer_context, template_name='index.html')

serializer = PaginatedPictureSerializer(pictures, context=serializer_context)
return Response(serializer.data, template_name='index.html')
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Tho I have to say it's quite stupid. It should really do that on it's own.