# Django REST Framework - let ListAPIView behave similar to pure ListView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, renderer

I am trying to convince `ListAPIView` to behave the way the `ListView` from pure Django does (that means, renders a template with an `object_list` variable, possibly some pagination stuff, and so on). This is what I tried:

```
class UserListView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny, )
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserListSerializer
    renderer_classes = (TemplateHTMLRenderer, )
    template_name = 'user/list.html'
```

Assume the `User` to be the builtin Django user model, `UserListSerializer` to be a `ModelSerializer` with `fields = "__all__"` and the template containing just a for loop over `object_list` displaying all the users.

When I try it, I get the following error:

`TypeError: context must be a dict rather than ReturnList.`

I must be doing something terribly wrong, I believe there must me a way to make use of the genericity and I just have no idea how.

Comment: any specific need to force Django to render a HTML view? IMHO, this is better implemented as a separate view not connected to Django REST Framework

Comment: What would you do if you will need to add REST API in the future? Break the DRY?

Comment: oh ok, I get your point, check out my blog post on how I design projects, might be of help to you - http://bitonator.github.io/mvmc-model-view-manager-controller-architecture/ - basically move your business logic into a separate layer so that you can call it from both an API controller and a regular view controller

Comment: I went through the blog post and still can't see how such thing could help me here...I still need to write both `ListAPIView` and `ListView`, your "manager logic" advises me to write the common stuff into a special layer, but then I would need some sort of adapters to inject the manager logic into those two views as they do not work the same, speaking for example in terms of permissions. Sure, it is possible, but I doubt it is the correct way to do it when Django REST Framework offers the HTML renderer.

Comment: I had a similar question, have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/q/18925358/631348

Comment: Is Django REST framework really so dumb that I need to write this manually?

Comment: Have a look at [this documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#setting-the-pagination-style) and see if it gets what you want out of the box. There might be some additional insight in this [issue](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/5236) on github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just stepped into a trap. Everything works as expected if I enable pagination, e. g. adding this into my settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}
```

I would never guess this would be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A serializer requires context in `dict` format but you are providing `ReturnList` which generated by renderer_classes.

I didn't get if you need `ListView` then why are you using `ListAPIView`? you are clearly rendering a templet instead JSON. So please mention specific reason you need to do that so that anyone can understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: There is a concern that I would need REST API in the future and I want to avoid breaking the DRY.

Comment: @karlosss How you will differentiate when to send templet and when to send json?
their are lot of case where page and JSON both needed but they all use tow different views pointing, serializer for JSON and form for templet. You also need to do that.

Comment: I imagine that once the view is written, the difference between template and JSON would be just in the `renderer_class` used, therefore a subclass of the view can be made, overriding this attribute. And as for your serializer/form point, `ModelForm` and `ModelSerializer` look exactly the same,  featuring `Meta` with `model` and `fields` attributes, so again, no big concern here.

Comment: @ashwinbande The client can use content negotiation to control whether json, xml, or html etc. is returned. DRF can change it's output based on HTTP headers sent by the client.